# golang string channel send/receive inconsistency

Tags: unit-testing, testing, go, channel

New to go. I'm using 1.5.1. I'm trying to accumulate a word list based on an incoming channel. However, my input channel (wdCh) is sometimes getting the empty string ("") during testing. I'm perplexed. I'd rather not have a test for the empty string before I add its accumulated count in my map. Feels like a hack to me.

```
package accumulator

import (
    "fmt"
    "github.com/stretchr/testify/assert"
    "testing"
)

var words map[string]int

func Accumulate(wdCh chan string, closeCh chan bool) {
    words = make(map[string]int)
    for {
        select {
        case word := <-wdCh:
            fmt.Printf("word = %s\n", word)
            words[word]++
        case <-closeCh:
            return
        }
    }
}

func pushWords(w []string, wdCh chan string) {
    for _, value := range w {
        fmt.Printf("sending word = %s\n", value)
        wdCh <- value
    }
    close(wdCh)
}

func TestAccumulate(t *testing.T) {
    sendWords := []string{"one", "two", "three", "two"}
    wMap := make(map[string]int)
    wMap["one"] = 1
    wMap["two"] = 2
    wMap["three"] = 1

    wdCh := make(chan string)
    closeCh := make(chan bool)

    go Accumulate(wdCh, closeCh)
    pushWords(sendWords, wdCh)

    closeCh <- true
    close(closeCh)

    assert.Equal(t, wMap, words)
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check out this article about [channel-axioms](http://dave.cheney.net/2014/03/19/channel-axioms).  Looks like there's a race between closing `wdCh` and sending true on the `closeCh` channel.

So the outcome depends on what gets scheduled first between `pushWords` returning and `Accumulate`.

If `TestAccumulate` runs first, sending true on `closeCh`, then when `Accumulate` runs it picks either of the two channels since they can both be run because `pushWords` closed `wdCh`.

> A receive from a closed channel returns the zero value immediately.

Until `closedCh` is signaled, `Accumulate` will randomly put one or more empty "" words in the map.

If `Accumulate` runs first then it's likely to put many empty strings in the word map as it loops until `TestAccumulate` runs and finally it sends a signal on `closeCh`.

An easy fix would be to move

`close(wdCh)`

after sending `true` on the `closeCh`.  That way `wdCh` can't return the zero value until after you've signaled on the `closeCh`.  Additionally, `closeCh <- true` blocks because `closeCh` doesn't have a buffer size, so `wdCh` won't get closed until after you've guaranteed that `Accumulate` has finished looping forever.

Comment: Or just remove that close statement altogether, since it doesn't do anything after that loop exits.

Comment: Moving the close after I did `close(closeCh)` worked.

Answer (score -2):

I think the reason is when you close the channle, "select" will although receive the signal.

So when you close "wdCh" in "func pushWords", the loop in Accumulate will receive signal from "<-wdCh".
May be you should add some code to test the action after channel is closed!

```
for {
    select {
    case word, ok := <-wdCh:
        if !ok {
            fmt.Println("channel wdCh is closed!")
            continue
        }
        fmt.Printf("word = %s\n", word)
        words[word]++
    case <-closeCh:
        return
    }
}
```

Comment: This causes the closed channel to turn the loop into a busy wait, which in turn can cause more problems